# Getting "json.hpp: No such file or directory" error despite having json.hpp in the same folder as main.cpp

Tags: c++, json

I'm trying to integrate the json c++ library from [nlohmann](https://github.com/nlohmann/json), while simply copying the 'single_include' file to the same directory as my main.cpp file. As per the integration [instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N3xD.png)

json.hpp is the single required file in single_include/nlohmann or released here. You need to add

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

// for convenience
using json = nlohmann::json;
```

But for some reason the compiler thinks that no such file exists there, and I have no idea what I could possibly do differently to make this work.

Full error I'm getting:

```
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: json.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <json.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

(I'm guessing that since the json.hpp file is right next to the main.cpp file, I shouldn't write `#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>` despite it's being written like that in the integration instructions, right?)

*This is how my project in VS Code [looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfQNB.png) at the moment

Comment: What are the errors it’s giving you in the json.hpp file? That seems to be where the issue is, not in the main.cpp file

Comment: The full error is
```main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: json.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <json.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.```

Comment: If you change it to #include “json.hpp” does that help?

Comment: The code and the error do not match.

Comment: #include "json.hpp"
solved it
bless you kind sir!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++, when headers are surrounded by angle brackets (`<>`), it searches for the headers in the include paths, which usually do not include the directory that your `main.cpp` file is located unless explicitly configured otherwise. However, when your headers are surrounded by double quotes, it searches the current directory, so you should include `"json.hpp"` instead of `<json.hpp>`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, as @crdrisko suggested, changing the <> to "" solves the issue.

Comment: It depends on how you're compiling the code. For g++ and clang, you can add a directory to the include path via `-I /path/to/directory`. For an IDE, you may have to search up where to find the include path in the project settings.

Comment: hmm, let's say I have some library files in /projectdir/lib/somelib.hpp, what would I need to write in the terminal for the main.cpp to properly use said hpp file? (using g++)

Answer (score 4):

For me, it turned out I havn't installed that yet so this solved my problem.

```
sudo apt install nlohmann-json-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo cd /usr/include/ && wget https://github.com/nlohmann/json/releases/download/v3.10.5/json.hpp
```

Comment: You shouldn't write stuff directly to `/usr`, it's supposed to be managed by your package manager.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to use this package instead:

```
sudo apt install nlohmann-json3-dev
```